# Expectation value with condition

Tags: probability, statistics

how can i show that:

$E[XY \vert X ] = XE[Y \vert X]$  for two random variables $X$ and $Y$

sorry this must be wrong what i meant was

$E[ E[XY \vert X ] ]= E [XE[Y \vert X]]$

Answer (score 3):

Ok I'll give you a hint. Does $E[3Y|X]=3E[Y|X]$? Can you prove this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using the nomenclature from [this article](http://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Conditional.html).

Let $f(x,y)$ be the joint probability density of $X$ and $Y$. Then
$$
g(x)=\int f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
is the probability density of $X$ and
$$
h(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x)}
$$
is the conditional density of $Y$ given $X$. Then
$$
\mathrm{E}[X\mathrm{E}[Y|X]]=\int x\left(\int y\,h(y|x)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{E}[\mathrm{E}[XY|X]]=\int\left(\int xy\,h(y|x)\,\mathrm{d}y\right)\,g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Comment: "E[Y|X] is the expected value of Y for a given X." This is not the definition of E[Y|X] (and absurd in many cases).

Comment: Sorry, that was my understanding, which is obviously flawed.

Comment: @Did: is what I have above incorrect?

Comment: The new version is "Since X is fixed for the evaluation of the expectation and since expectation is linear". Unfortunately I don't know what "X is fixed for the evaluation of the expectation" means and I don't see how "expectation is linear" is related. Why not being rigorous, why not using the definition?

Comment: @Did: I am learning while doing. I think I have properly converted my ideas to the case of continuous random variables.

Comment: New formulation, but now: what do you call P(Y|X) and P(X) and why E[E[XY|X]] should be equal to the RHS of the second identity? New mysteries... (And I wonder why, instead of explaining version N when asked for explanations, you shift to an entirely different version N+1. This can go on forever.)

Comment: @Did: Perhaps I am overloading notation. I was trying to explain what I had meant by $X\mathrm{E}[Y|X]=\mathrm{E}[XY|X]$. What I mean by $\mathrm{P}(X)$ is the distribution so that $$\int_E\mathrm{P}(X=x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{P}[X\in E]$$ and $\mathrm{P}(Y|X)$ is a distribution such that $$\int_E\int_F\mathrm{P}(Y=y|X=x)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{P}(X=x)\,\mathrm{d}x =\mathrm{P}[X\in E\land Y\in F]$$

Comment: As I said, instead on relying on some solid definition of conditional expectation (which, by the way, makes the question trivial, and for every random variables, not necessarily discrete), you are losing yourself (and the reader) into unorthodox notations (note how to define $P(Y\mid X)$ as some unique distribution, you are actually forced to consider every $P(Y\mid X=x)$ simultaneously?) and into shaky steps such as why (if I follow you correctly) $\mathrm{E}[XY|X]$ should be $\int xy\mathrm{P}(Y|X)\,\mathrm{d}y$ for $x=X$. This is not a service to the askers.

Comment: @Did: I have used what I hope is more standard nomenclature from the cited article. As I mentioned before I was overloading $\mathrm{P}$. I have hopefully fixed that.

Comment: I won't even ask about the downvote, but I will note that I have edited the answer since the downvote.

Comment: In case you are wondering, I did not vote on this page. For the record, the statement that "I won't even ask about the downvote, but..." is odd.

Comment: @Did: I didn't think that was your downvote. I believe I understand the OP's confusion and why the expectations are equal. I am just struggling with the formalism. I have read the cited article and I have tried using the nomenclature from that to improve my answer.

Comment: @Did: when I get a downvote, I usually ask "would the downvoter care to comment?", but in this case, I have been having so much trouble with the answer that I understand why someone would downvote.

Comment: Which is why you mention the downvote? I don't get it.

Comment: @Did: I mentioned the downvote to let the downvoter know that I had edited the answer since the downvote. I guess I could have dispensed with the commentary and simply said that "I have edited the answer since the downvote."

Comment: @Did: is it okay with you if we (or I) remove the comments above? The initial comments are no longer relevant and the later comments are about the downvote.